# Get data object from case statement

Tags: haskell

Assume I have:

```
data Z = A Int Int Int Int | B String  | Char

exampleFunc :: Z -> IO ()
exampleFunc (A a b c d) = someOtherFunc (A a b c d)
```

Is there a way to pass on the A that gets pattern matched without having to use the constructor in the function definition again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can use the [**as pattern `@`**](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.17.1):

```
exampleFunc :: Z -> IO ()
exampleFunc x@(A a b c d) = someOtherFunc x
```

Furthermore by using *record syntax*, you can even fully omit the parameters `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in the head of the function:

```
exampleFunc :: Z -> IO ()
exampleFunc x@A{} = someOtherFunc x
```

This is short for the above code fragment, but without having to specify the parameters. This can be useful if you for instance later plan to change the number of parameters, and you want to prevent having to change all function definitions that rely only on the constructor type (and not the parameters). [*Record pattern*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#Introduction_to_records) can also be useful in case you are only interested in a subset of the parameters.

Since patterns can be used recursively (a pattern as parameter of a constructor), you can also recursively use the as pattern. For example:

```
yetAnotherFunction :: Maybe Z -> IO ()
yetAnotherFunction x@(Just y@A{}) = -- ...
```

So here we obtain a reference to the `Just (A a b c d)` object, as well as to the `A a b c d` object. Apparentely `yetAnotherFunction` is not interested in the parameters of the `A`  constructor.

Comment: Can you do (Just x@A{})?

Comment: @Carbon: sure. The *as* is a type of pattern. Since you can recurse on patterns, you can recurse with as patterns as well. In this case you thus will match the `Just (A a b c d)` pattern, but you are only interested in a reference to the content in the `Just` constructor.